# Change size of div depending on how many are visible

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need some help changing the size of a div depending on how many are visible.

Two things aren't working so far. The third thing I'd like to do I'm not even sure how to write. Here's the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d66ynwon/2/).

First, I can't even manage to get the correct count of how many are visible right now. I thought this would work:

```
var count = $('.box:visible').length;

alert(count);
```

But it turns up zero every time, no matter how many are visible!

Second, I need to change the width of the divs based on how many are visible. Maybe this would work if the counting thing was working? As it is now, they are all 30% wide.

```
$('p').click(function() {
  if count = 1 {
    $('.box:visible').css('width', '70%');
  } else if count = 2 {
    $('.box:visible').css('width', '40%');
  } else if count >= 3 {
    $('.box:visible').css('width', '30%');
  }
})
```

If only one is open I'd like that one to be 70% wide. If two are open, they should both be 40% wide. And if more than three are open they should all be 30% wide!

And, in my JSfiddle, three of the divs are all in the same column. So, that means (if my above code was working) if boxes 1, 4, and 5 were all open they would all be 30% wide, but there would only be two columns, so I'd actually want them to be 40% wide! Can someone help with my syntax for this? Would I just have to write more if else statements?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You need parentheses around your `if` conditions, and you should be using `===` for comparison: `if (count === 1) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parentheses around your `if` conditions, and you should be using `===` for comparison: `if (count === 1) { ... }`. Also, you need to update the `length` of your visible boxes every time the event handler is run, so move `var count = $('.box:visible').length` into your handler.

```js
$('p:first-child').click(function() {
  $('#box1').toggle();
})

$('p:nth-child(2)').click(function() {
  $('#box2').toggle();
})

$('p:nth-child(3)').click(function() {
  $('#box3').toggle();
})

$('p:nth-child(4)').click(function() {
  $('#box4').toggle();
})

$('p:nth-child(5)').click(function() {
  $('#box5').toggle();
})


$('p').click(function() {
    var count = $('.box:visible').length;
  if (count === 1) {
    $('.box:visible').css('width', '70%');
  } else if (count === 2) {
    $('.box:visible').css('width', '40%');
  } else if (count >= 3) {
    $('.box:visible').css('width', '30%');
  }
})
```

```css
* *::before *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 10vh;
  margin-bottom: 2vw;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

nav p {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#container {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: left;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.box {
  display: none;
  align-self: center;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 2vh 1%;
}

#box1 {
  order: 1;
  height: 96vh;
  background-color: coral;
}

#box2 {
  order: 2;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: darkred;
}

#box3 {
  order: 3;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: moccasin;
}

#box4 {
  order: 4;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: salmon;
}

#box5 {
  order: 5;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
</nav>

<div id="container">
  <div class="box" id="box1">
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box2">
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box3">
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box4">
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box5">
  </div>
</div>
```